# How do I handle a large number of properties that initialize a class?

Tags: c++

I have a class that requires a large number of properties for initialization:

```
Hand hand = new Hand();
hand->skinColor(Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.2));
hand->indexFingerLength(0.5);
hand->middleFingerLength(0.6);
hand->ringFingerLength(0.55);
...
hand->init(); // Builds the hand model
```

These properties are only valid to modify up until the call to init(), which uses them to build the class. The problem is that these properties can still be modified after the call to init() to no effect, an interface which could mislead the user to think that they will have an effect.

Is there a better way to refactor this other than moving all the properties into an argument list for init()?

Comment: A class with many properties is, in my opinion, a bad code smell.

Comment: @Federico Why is that so? In OO philiosophy entites of our thinking should be mapped to classes. If I have a complex entity, this will result in a complex class.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I think the concern is a coherent class state represented by many attributes vs many unrelated properties. The first is fine while the second is a smell.

Comment: @Mark. Interesting. Could you define (or link a definition) of "attribute" and "property"? A property would be implemented as a member variable; how about an attribute?

Comment: @Hyperboreus in the given example, a good class would be `Hand` with five "`Finger` class" attributes, one for each finger, each of which has its `length` property. I'm talking about a good abstraction, of course, I don't really see a need for a `Finger` class here, especially if the fingers have only a length and nothing else. But still I see as a good OO practice to abstract them in another class so, maybe, we can pass the 5 `Finger`s in `Hand`'s constructor

Comment: @Federico: De acuerdo. Or if the fingers really only have length and array over float, like float fingerLengths [5]. Supposing that you don't have more than five fingers on one hand.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
struct structHandParms
{
  param1;
  param2;
  param3;
  ...

};

structHandParms stParams;

Hand hand = new Hand(stParams)
```

Comment: Could be improved by making params optional.

Answer (score 3):

You could add a "Hand_Init" struct that was passed to the constructor:

```
Hand_Init hand_init;
hand_init.skinColor = Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.2);
hand_init.indexFingerLength = 0.5;
hand_init.middleFingerLength = 0.6;
hand_init.ringFingerLength = 0.55;
Hand hand = new Hand(hand_init);
```

That way as soon as the constructor call completes, the hand is initialized, and you don't have a bunch of anonymous arguments that could cause confusion.

Answer (score 3):

If you're going to create more than one `Hand`, then maybe use something like the [Builder Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Builder_pattern).

```
// set properties
HandBuilder hb;
hb.skinColor(Color(0.5, 0.5, 0.2));
hb.indexFingerLength(0.5);
hb.middleFingerLength(0.6);
hb.ringFingerLength(0.55);
// create object
Hand hand = hb.buildHand();
```

Answer (score 2):

This totally screams to have the logic in the constructor instead of separate methods followed by init. Then it's completely obvious (and enforced by the compiler) that they can't be changed later. If there are a lot of parameters, group them all into a struct which is populated and passed into the constructor instead of 25 separate parameters.

Answer (score 1):

"the call to init(), which uses them to build the class" really builds a class or does it initialise the instance of this class?

Why don't you do your whole initialisation in the ctor and pass the required values as parameters?

Comment: then you can end up passing dozens of objects, which ends up being just as messy, unless you used an initializer struct like above

Comment: Well, then you have to populate the struct instead of populating the parameters of the ctor. That just moves the problem and doesn't change anything.

Comment: True, but I find large parameter lists very confusing and difficult to modify, whereas if each line is labeled as to what property you are changing, it is more explicit and easier to change later on

Comment: Beauty (and hence readability and explicity) is in the eye of the beholder. I find my co-workers coding style just ugly and unreadable. Same thing he says about mine. This is where corporate code style guidelines must come into play.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a good reason to maintain a documentation and user manual for your project or maybe you can change to send a descriptor to your class. Then, you create the descriptor, fill it with the configuration and sends all the information at once to the constructor.

Answer (score 0):

You could solve the problem of post init() modification by throwing an exception.  This would prevent a user from making a call to one of the setting functions and expecting it to do something.

As an alternative, you could create a HandParameter class/struct.  This object would be responsible for gathering all the data you need to have about the Hand object.  Next, you could make your Hand object's init() function take a HandParameter as its only argument.

```
struct HandParam
{
    // Whatever settings you need
};

class Hand
{
    bool initialized;
    // other private data
    public:
        Hand();
        Hand( const HandParam& params ); // Calls the init() funciton with params
        void init( const HandParam& params ); // sets up hand and sets initialized to true
    // Whatever else you need in your class
};
```

Good Luck!